# How to pass json arrray that is get by the help of ajax into the div or view of codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I need to send a JSON array that i have received using AJAX scroll function to the div or HTML response of my view.

How can I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var url= '<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>';
        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');

        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:url,
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(html){

                 //alert(html);
                 var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(html);            
              var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
              //alert(json);
            /*
              var json =" [{'id':1,'name':'Test1'},{'id':2,'name':'Test2'}]";
              var jsonArray = eval('(' + json + ')');
            for (i in jsonArray)
            {
             alert(jsonArray[i]["name"]);
            }
            */
             // alert(json.id);
              var jsonArray = eval('(' + json + ')');

             $PostId=jsonArray[4]["id"];
            alert($PostId);

            for(i in jsonArray)
            {
            $status=jsonArray[i]["status"];
            $status_image=jsonArray[i]["status_image"];
            $multimage=jsonArray[i]["multimage"];
              }
              //alert(Lastid);

                  $('.load-more').attr('lastID',$PostId);
                    $('#result_table').append($status_image);
                 } 
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The `jsonArray` is giving me errors showing that array to conversion so how can i pass the complete array to be used in my view with HTML element.